# C++: container replacement for vector/deque for huge sizes

Tags: c++, boost, stl, containers, large-data

so my applications has containers with 100 million and more elements.

I'm on the hunt for a container which behaves - time-wise - better than std::deque (let alone std::vector) with respect to frequent insertions and deletions all over the container ... including near the middle. Access time to the n-th element does not need to be as fast as vector, but should definetely be better than full traversal like in std::list (which has a huge memory overhead per element anyway).

Elements should be treated ordered by index (like vector, deque, list), so std::set or std::unordered_set also do not work well.

Before I sit down and code such a container myself: has anyone seen such a beast already? I'm pretty sure the STL hasn't anything like this, looking to BOOST I did not find something I could use but I may be wrong.

Any hints?

Comment: Like the topic as I've once coded datasets (quadtrees for terrain rendering, e.g.) of 32GiB and bigger (with memory mapping). But I must ask "what have you looked at already" :)

Comment: Just a note that vector performs better that deque for operations in the middle... Especially if you add a `reserve(100 million)` initially.

Comment: @phresnel I looked at STL and Boost (v1.50) in the container descriptions whether one of the containers claimed to have what I need, no luck.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, indeed. But then a deque is faster when inserting, deleting in the first ~40% of the container. I once benchmarked a 50m element container, inserting and deleting randomly but once at every position. Difference was small enough for me to take deque due to added benefit of constant insertions/dleetions at the ends.

Comment: @BaCh: Btw, 100 million is not a large number, that's just 95 Megas. How big are those elements actually?

Comment: 88 bytes per element. Smaller data sets I used so far show that once I have the X million elements in a container, I need to perform insertion/deletion on roughly 10% to 20% of the element, all across the container. So worst case (atm) would be 100m element and 20m insertions/deletions, on average copying at least half of the container (when using vector/deque). I tried it out with vector/deque, definetely no fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the performance characteristics that you want with a skip list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist

It's the "indexable" part that you're interested in, of course -- you don't actually want the items to be sorted. So some modification is needed that I leave as an exercise.

You might find that 100 million list nodes begins to strain a 32 bit address space, but probably not an issue in 64 bits.

Comment: Yep, that's a good one. I had something similar in one of my more complex classes already, but now hoped for an already existing class ... exercise is nice, but if I could get around writing one myself, I could concentrate more on the part of my program which actually just need such a class. But best answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole STL replacement for big data, in case your app is centric to such data:

- STXXL - http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/

---

edit: I was actually a bit fast to answer. 100 million is not really a large number. E.g., if each element is one byte, you could save it in a 96MiB array. So whether STXXL is any useful, the size of an element should be significantly bigger.

Comment: Nice, but not what I need. Data still needs to be kept in memory as access to it is at times pretty random and this would trash the disk I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the data is highly sparse, i.e. has lots of zeroes or can be expressed as such, I would highly recommend a data structure that takes advantage of that:

- [sparselib++](http://math.nist.gov/sparselib++/) for matrices
- [sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/) for hash maps

2) Hash maps should do O(1) for all the operations you describe and the sparsehash implementation I mentioned earlier is particularly space-efficient; it also includes a `sparsetable` type which is a bit more low-level and can be used in place of an array.

3) If the strict ordering is not that important (it probably is, because you mentioned elements should be treated ordered by index), you can `swap` the elements you want to erase to the end of the vector and then `resize` to do removal in O(1). Insertion would just be `push_back`.

Comment: Speaking of space-efficient hash maps, there's also [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Ah, sparsity I forgot to mention. No, data is not sparse at all as in a container with n elements, all n elements are used. And strict ordering unfortunately is important.

Comment: @BaCh, what do you use the indices for exactly? Is there perhaps an order of magnitude difference between `insert`, `remove` and retrieval frequency, so we can prioritize?

Comment: I normally use iterators to go through the container, but from time to time a direct access to the n-th element is needed. And then I really need the n-th element in the container, because the container represents an ordered sequence (well, ordered by index).

Answer (score 0):

Try a hash map. The STL has several, all with the unordered naming prefix , such as unorderd_map, etc. It has constant time insertion and look up given a good hashing algorithm. With your 'huge' data set the hash map would most likely cover your needs. Making a slight change to the application to cover the differences in the interfaces is trivial.

Comment: maps and hash_maps fail the "ordered by index" prerequisite.

Comment: @BaCh key value pair , int , data ... int is the index. simple fix.

Comment: Except that the index for half the items change when you do an insert or delete, so half your hash map needs to be updated. Not optimal.

Comment: Maybe you could use a *really* sparse key algorithm on a map? If you use 32-bit key for 100 million items, that's 40+ key values range for every item. Using 64-bit means ranges of 180+ billion key values for every item. Do you know in advance how many items you have? You would have to check for collisions and account for that of course but that's easy (do find before insert, if it exists move to the next or previous element depending on what you want to do, sum the halves of the keys of elements and you have the new key)

Comment: @ierceg Not a bad idea. I would need to check the memory overhead for 100m elements, but definitively worth a shot as 180 b key values between initial element would be more than enough. With STL I can only take map though, not unordered_map, as I also need to walk through the data set (in order) from the first to the last element. Need to check Google sparse libraries though.